# How do I implement "move forward" action for Google Street View?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I am building a custom view on a webpage that displays Street View in one of my DIVs. I'm using the V3 Javascript API to control navigation in the view. My custom controls are actually in a different DIV from Street View on the same page.

`myPano.setPov({heading:someNewHeading, pitch:someNewPitch, zoom:someNewZoom})` is what I use to tilt and pan/rotate around the scene and it works fine. I'm unsure how to replicate the action of moving forward which would be akin to pressing the up arrow.

In Street View, the up arrow moves along a path even if the user's POV heading is a little out of alignment with the path. How do I use `setPosition()` or similarly how do I calculate a long/lat that mimics this forward movement?

Thank you in advance for your brainpower and contribution(s).

Answer (score 1):

```
function difference(link) {
  return Math.abs(pano.pov.heading%360 - link.heading);
}

function moveForward() {
  var curr;
  for(i=0; i < pano.links.length; i++) {
    var differ = difference(pano.links[i]);
    if(curr == undefined) {
      curr = pano.links[i];
    }

    if(difference(curr) > difference(pano.links[i])) {
      curr = curr = pano.links[i];
    }
  }
  pano.setPano(curr.pano);
}
```

where pano is google.maps.StreetViewPanorama

Answer (score 1):

```
function difference(link) {

    var diff = Math.abs(panorama.pov.heading % 360 - link.heading);
    if(diff>180)
       diff=Math.abs(360-diff);

    return diff;

}
```

I would consider to use this function difference instead of the one proposed by raz0r bacause it doesn't monitor the right way.

For instance (image below):
Link 0: backward
Link 1: forward
Link 2: left (College Avenue)

In the raz0r difference we have 173 for backward and 353 for forward and since in his function it gets the minimum this means when i call moveForward() I'm going backward!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found something :D. For the moment, inspect the sources of http://www.mapchannels.com/mm/streetview/driver.htm and http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/streetview/streetview_directions.html. Found them on http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/7150eccbba9dfe40/0ca970e639a2c240, so credits go to the author and to the answerers over there. Hope it helps :D.

1. Seems to be related to followLink, and it doesn't seem to work locally